# How to get logically inserted fact or insrt fact in code in Drools guvnor

Tags: drools, guvnor

My guvnor rule is like :

```
Rule "aa" 
 dialect "mvel" 
  when 
    Fund( amount> 10000 ) 

then 
 Alert fact0 = new Alert(); 
 fact0.setSummary( "hi" ); 
 insert( fact0 ); 
end
```

and using stateless knowledge session.  Now I want to get that `fact0` in code. How to do that?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most drools-friendly way to do it is by using queries. Another option is to use ksession.getObjects(). You can take a look to this answer: [Retrieving facts of a specific type from working memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035209/retrieving-facts-of-a-specific-type-from-working-memory/15042055#15042055)

Hope it helps,