# How do I retrieve a fact from drools session?

Tags: java, drools

Assume that I have a class as follows:

```
public class A {
    private int id1;  
    private int id2;  
    HashMap<String, String> attrMap;  
}  


StatefulKnowledgeSession session = knowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(); 
session.insert(a1);
session.insert(a2);
session.insert(a3);
session.insert(a4);
```

Now how do I retrieve the fact from the session who has `id1 = 2`.
I know that I can retrieve the facts using `getFactHandle(Object)`, but here I want to retrieve fact using one member value.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get those facts out of your ksession, then you may want to use a query. 
For more information, please take a look at my answer here: [Retrieving facts of a specific type from working memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035209/retrieving-facts-of-a-specific-type-from-working-memory/15042055#15042055)

Even if my answer in the other post is about extracting facts for certain class, it can be easily modified to do what you are looking for.

Comment: I have given this queri in drl file `query "findItemsForGw" (int id, String Name)
 account : Account(name.equals(Name), roll == id)
end` . How do I pass arguments to the query? `QueryResults res = session.getQueryResults(findItemsForGw, ??)`

Comment: I am able to call the query using arguments. But and condition is not working for the query.