# can we access working memory fact of drools rule engine in jbpm6 script task?

Tags: java, drools, jbpm

is there a way to access working memory fact of drools rule engine in jbpm6 script task?

I have a model class : Application.java
Rule : check if salary is > 10000 (part of rule group : salaryCheck )

jbpm flow : start -> salaryCheck(rule task, associated with rule group : salaryCheck) -> updateScore(script task) -> end

updateScore - script rask code:

```
System.out.println(System.out.println((Application)(kcontext.getKieRuntime().getFactHandles().toArray()[0]));
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle cannot be cast to org.model.Application
```

Updated script task:

```
import org.model.Application
import org.drools.runtime.rule.QueryResults
import org.drools.runtime.rule.QueryResultsRow

QueryResults results = kcontext.getKieRuntime().getQueryResults( "getObjectsOfApplication" ); 
for ( QueryResultsRow row : results ) {
    Application applicantion = ( Application ) row.get( "$result" ); 
    application.setScore(700);
    System.out.println("Application object :: "+ application);
}
```

Added Query to rule drl file

```
query "getObjectsOfApplication"
    $result: Application()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`getFactHandles()` is definitely not the method you are looking for. The method think you are looking for is `getObjects()`. Either way, getting the first element of the returned collection without any validation seems dangerous to me. You can't even guarantee that order of the elements in the returned collection will remain the same between different invocations.

A better approach would be to use the version of `getObjects()` that accepts an `ObjectFilter` parameter. An even better and more 'declarative' approach would be to define a query in that returns the exact object you are looking for. You can then execute the query using `kcontext.getKieRuntime().getQueryResults()`.

You can get a better understanding on any of these 2 approaches (using an `ObjectFilter` or a query) in this thread: [Retrieving facts of a specific type from working memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035209/retrieving-facts-of-a-specific-type-from-working-memory)

---

**EDIT:**

The post I suggested about using a query or an `ObjectFilter` is Drools 5 code. In Drools 6, the API classes were moved to a different package. These are the imports you should use if you want to invoke a query in your code:

- `org.kie.api.runtime.rule.QueryResults`
- `org.kie.api.runtime.rule.QueryResultsRow`

These classes are both part of the `kie-api` project.

Comment: Updated question above with modified script task. Getting compilation errors now.text=Error importing : 'org.drools.runtime.rule.QueryResults'], Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=process/sample.bpmn, line=1, column=0
   text=Error importing : 'org.drools.runtime.rule.QueryResultsRow'], Message [id=3, level=ERROR, path=process/sample.bpmn, line=-1, column=0
   text=Process Compilation error Only a type can be imported. org.drools.runtime.rule.QueryResultsRow resolves to a package
Only a type can be imported. org.drools.runtime.rule.QueryResults resolves to a package

Comment: If you are using jBPM 5, then you need to add `knowledge-api` dependency to your runtime environment.