# Its possible to know which objects are in the working memory of drools ?

Tags: java, drools

i was trying to use debug for drools on eclipse. And would be better if i could see which objects are in the working memory. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be seen as a duplicate of this other question: [Retrieving facts of a specific type from working memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035209/retrieving-facts-of-a-specific-type-from-working-memory/15042055#15042055)

You just need to generalize the proposed answers in that question to retrieve all of the Objects instead of the ones belonging to a specific class.

Hope it helps,